# It is possible to configure Squid with authenticated and not authenticated users?

Tags: squid, centos7

I need to configure two types of access in Squid:

- Users with privileges (AD authentication) to access audio-video and social networking sites;
- Users without privileges, just few sites

## I'm using:

### CentOS 7

SELinux Enforcing
Firewall allowing access through 3128 port

### Squid 3.3.8

```
...
acl local_network src 192.168.0.0/24
external_acl_type user_priv ipv4 %LOGIN /usr/lib64/squid/ext_ldap_group_acl -R -K \
-h example.com \
-b "dc=example,dc=com" \
-D user@DOMAIN \
-w password \
-f "(&(objectclass=person)(sAMAccountName=%v)(memberof=cn=%a,ou=ADMINISTRATION,dc=example,dc=com))"

acl access_priv external user_priv PRIVILEGED_USERS

http_access allow access_priv
http_access allow local_network

url_rewrite_program /usr/bin/squidGuard -c /etc/squid/squidGuard.conf  
...
```

### SquidGuard 1.4

```
ldapbinddn cn=User,ou=TI,dc=example,dc=com
ldapbindpass password
ldapcachetime  300  

src user_priv {
    ldapusersearch  ldap://ad.example.com/dc=example,dc=com?sAMAccountName?sub?(&(sAMAccountName=%s)(memberof=cn=PRIVILEGED_USERS,ou=ADMINISTRATION,dc=example,dc=com)
}  

user_priv {
    pass !ads !porn audio-video social_networks whitelist
    redirect http://squid.example.com/cgi-bin/squidGuard.cgi?clientaddr=%a+clientname=%n+clientuser=%i+clientgroup=%s+targetgroup=%t+url=%u
}
default {
    pass !ads !porn !audio-video !social_networks whitelist
    redirect http://squid.example.com/cgi-bin/squidGuard.cgi?clientaddr=%a+clientname=%n+clientuser=%i+clientgroup=%s+targetgroup=%t+url=%u
}
```

I couldn't make it work. I tried to change the order of the acls but it didn't work as I need.
Or the users without authentication not have any access or the privileged users not have their private access.

Any idea?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I don't think so because you need to enable NTLM module inside squid configuration.
The solutions could be by installing 2 differents squids or activate 2 squids on two different instance.
Just for clarify it's not a good choice to enable user auth on squid, because your AD will be involved every time by squid and the browsing it will be slow.
Last but not least your users will hate you.
:-)
Regards

Comment: Thanks for your advice, Francesco.
I'm considering to use two different Squid configurations.
About authentication in AD I have no escape.

Answer (score 0):

SquidGuard 1.4 does not support Squid 3.3.8
You need to patch squidguard to work with newer squid versions.
http://bugs.squid-cache.org/show_bug.cgi?id=3978

or use another redirector.

Comment: here it is working fine.